# IOS10: badge count not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, badge

I am using the following code to display a number as badge at my apps icon:

```
func triggerNotification(iAmountToday: Int) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert]) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.badge = iAmountToday
      content.categoryIdentifier = "com.psv.localNotification"
      let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false)
      let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "AmountTodayUpdate", content: content, trigger: trigger)

      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
      center.addNotificationRequest(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
          print (error)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Although no error is thrown, the badge is never shown at the apps icon.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Try this. content.badge = iAmountToday as NSNumber? also check iAmountToday is having value or not.

Comment: Hi @Wolverine, I tried this but no effect. iAmountToday is at least 0 - I checked that, too

Comment: try setting it to at least 1

Comment: Nope, does not help!  :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 3.0, iOS 10.

You should replace:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert]) { (granted, error) in
```

with:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
```

This worked for me.

Best regards
Fabio